# How to find owner socket of sk_buff in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm trying to find the owner socket of an `sk_buff` instance, say, `skb`. My ultimate goal is to find a specific TCP option and somehow let the user space application to know. I plan to set a socket option when I find the TCP option and let the user space app to call `getsockopt()`. Therefore I need to know the ownership between `sk_buff` and `sock`.

I find there is a field in sk_buff:

```
struct sock *sk;
```

However, when I try to retrieve this field at [`tcp_parse_options`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?v=3.11#L3418) in `tcp_input.c`, I always get `skb->sk == NULL`.

So I'm wondering how can I find the owner here?

Also, I find 3 places that seems to set the owner socket:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?v=3.11#L4181

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?v=3.11#L4196

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?v=3.11#L4456

I also add a new flag in `sk_buff` for indicating and set it at `tcp_parse_options`. Then I check this flag at these three places. But none of them shows the flag is set so that I cannot determine whether to set the socket option.

Any idea or suggestion for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sk_buff (skb) you can get the sock (sk) with something like this:

```
const struct tcphdr *th = tcp_hdr(skb);
struct sock *sk = __inet_lookup_skb(&tcp_hashinfo, skb, th->source, th->dest);
if (sk)
    struct socket* = sk->sk_socket;
```

That worked for me. Don't forget to add the right headers.

Comment: Local BH must be disabled before call __inet_lookup_skb

Comment: @sim What is local BH?

Comment: sk_peer_pid is available for UNIX socket only, it's always NULL for other socket family. How could you find the owner from struct sock?

Comment: @daisy local_bh_disable()

Comment: @sim Thanks, and I found this link very useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260087/local-bh-disable-preempt-disable-local-irq-disable